# Android Image map

Tags: android, gesture, tap

I use the following code to display a very large bitmap which is zoomable by pinch gesture

```
package com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.R.id;

import java.io.IOException;

public class DemoActivity extends Activity {

private static final String STATE_SCALE = "state-scale";
private static final String STATE_CENTER_X = "state-center-x";
private static final String STATE_CENTER_Y = "state-center-y";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    try {
        SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView = (SubsamplingScaleImageView)findViewById(id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageAsset("DSC00266.jpg");

        if (savedInstanceState != null && 
                savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SCALE) &&
                savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_CENTER_X) &&
                savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_CENTER_Y)) {
            imageView.setScaleAndCenter(savedInstanceState.getFloat(STATE_SCALE), new PointF(savedInstanceState.getFloat(STATE_CENTER_X), savedInstanceState.getFloat(STATE_CENTER_Y)));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(DemoActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Could not load asset", e);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView = (SubsamplingScaleImageView)findViewById(id.imageView);
    outState.putFloat(STATE_SCALE, imageView.getScale());
    PointF center = imageView.getCenter();
    if (center != null) {
        outState.putFloat(STATE_CENTER_X, center.x);
        outState.putFloat(STATE_CENTER_Y, center.y);
    }
}
}
```

the gesture is handled by a separate class called SubsamplingScaleImageView.java which has the following code to handle the pinch and zoom

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    PointF vCenterEnd;
    float vDistEnd;
    flingMomentum = null;
    flingFrom = null;
    // Detect flings
    if (detector == null || detector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Abort if not ready
    if (vTranslate == null) {
        return true;
    }
    int touchCount = event.getPointerCount();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_1_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN:
            if (touchCount >= 2) {
                // Start pinch to zoom. Calculate distance between touch points and center point of the pinch.
                float distance = distance(event.getX(0), event.getX(1), event.getY(0), event.getY(1));
                scaleStart = scale;
                vDistStart = distance;
                vTranslateStart = new PointF(vTranslate.x, vTranslate.y);
                vCenterStart = new PointF((event.getX(0) + event.getX(1))/2, (event.getY(0) + event.getY(1))/2);
                isZooming = true;
            } else {
                // Start one-finger pan
                vTranslateStart = new PointF(vTranslate.x, vTranslate.y);
                vCenterStart = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());
            }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (touchCount >= 2 && isZooming) {
                // Calculate new distance between touch points, to scale and pan relative to start values.
                vDistEnd = distance(event.getX(0), event.getX(1), event.getY(0), event.getY(1));
                vCenterEnd = new PointF((event.getX(0) + event.getX(1))/2, (event.getY(0) + event.getY(1))/2);
                scale = Math.min(maxScale, (vDistEnd / vDistStart) * scaleStart);

                // Translate to place the source image coordinate that was at the center of the pinch at the start
                // at the center of the pinch now, to give simultaneous pan + zoom.
                float vLeftStart = vCenterStart.x - vTranslateStart.x;
                float vTopStart = vCenterStart.y - vTranslateStart.y;
                float vLeftNow = vLeftStart * (scale/scaleStart);
                float vTopNow = vTopStart * (scale/scaleStart);
                vTranslate.x = vCenterEnd.x - vLeftNow;
                vTranslate.y = vCenterEnd.y - vTopNow;

                fitToBounds();
                refreshRequiredTiles(false);
            } else if (!isZooming) {
                // One finger pan - translate the image
                vTranslate.x = vTranslateStart.x + (event.getX() - vCenterStart.x);
                vTranslate.y = vTranslateStart.y + (event.getY() - vCenterStart.y);
                fitToBounds();
                refreshRequiredTiles(false);
            }
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_UP:
            if (event.getPointerCount() < 2) {
                isZooming = false;
            }
            // Trigger load of tiles now required
            refreshRequiredTiles(true);
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I now want to be able to double tap on an area once I have zoomed in and for the app to tell me the coordinates of the double tap

I know i need to put code into the on touch motion event but I cant work out how to implement it

Has anyone got any ideas how I do it?

Any help appreciated

Mark

Answer (score 0):

The view is designed to be easily extended by subclassing so you can add extra functionality (e.g. overlaid graphics). Alternatively, in simple cases like this where all you want to do is add a touch event detector, you can do it within your activity or fragment by creating a `GestureDetector`, overriding `onDoubleTap`, and setting an `OnTouchListener` on the view that returns false when this detector doesn't handle the event. As long as you don't override `onScroll` or `onFling` this works fine.

The example below illustrates this. It also shows how to convert screen coordinates to the coordinates on the source image.

I have tested this with the version I pushed back in September, and the latest version pushed today, but there have been a few commits in the last few days where it may not have worked. Make sure you stick with the version from September or ideally upgrade to the latest.

```
final GestureDetector detector = new GestureDetector(getActivity(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        PointF sCoords = imageView.viewToSourceCoord(e.getX(), e.getY());
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Screen: " + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY() + "; Image: " + sCoords.x + ", " + sCoords.y, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
});
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return detector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    }
});
```